# after migrating to apollo client 3.0, using "withApollo" hoc throwing could not find client context error

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

TLDR;  managed to pull up a codesandbox with the issue, please have a [look here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-pike-78uvb).

[image]things were working fine while using react-apollo 2.5, now we have started the process of migrating to 3.0.

snapshot of the relevant portion of my package.json

```
    "@apollo/client": "^3.0.0-beta.19",
    "@apollo/react-components": "^3.1.3",
    "@apollo/react-hoc": "^3.1.3",
```

Now I am getting the below error

```
Could not find "client" in the context of ApolloConsumer. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>.
```

The outermost component of my App is indeed the ApolloProvider,

the way I import **ApolloProvider** after migration is shown below

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
```

also I have taken care to import the **withApollo** hoc from **"@apollo/react-hoc"** as mentioned in migration docs.

Isn't migration just changing the versions in package.json and imports? or is there anything specific I need to know when creating the apollo client instance?

Please find below, the code used for creating client instance

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQLURL,
  }),
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the migration docs, you shouldn't import `withApollo` hoc from `@apollo/react-hoc`

You should use hoc package from `@apollo/client`

```
import { withApollo } from "@apollo/client/react/hoc";
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/#apolloreact-hoc-and-apolloreact-components